# Different layout for single category

Tags: category, layout

I have 2 categories with different layout/page design. 
However i need the first category (lets call it Artists) to have two different layouts/page design relative to how i went to the category. So, if i clicked at the topmenu Artists it need one layout/page design, and if i clicked at the category list item, artists,  it need another design.

Any suggestions?

I was thinking about using a string in the url like ?specialartistview or ?shopview to define the layout/page design, but don't know if thats possible?

A solution could be just dublicating a category, but that's not what i prefer in this case. I need it as dynamicly as possible :)

Comment: Did any of the answers prove useful for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want different 'branding' you might want to look into using 2 shopviews that both use the same category tree. This way you can assign a different theme, or some modifications on a common theme to create the different designs.

Having 2 different designs for the same page in one webshop (or website) is quite confusing for users and might lead to issues with the way Google indexes the shop. So separating them by using different stores and urls might be a nice way to go.

Answer (score 1):

'Topmenu', as it is called in the layout xml, is the main site navigation.

By default, if you were to click on any link in that menu you would follow the link through to the new page. That new page's new 'layout' or 'design' can be specified from within the admin control panel under `Catalog > Manage Categories > (Choose Category) > Design`.

Comment: I know that. My issue is that i need a different layout for the same category depending on if the customer clicked the category in product list, og he clicked the category name in the menu (Static menu)